# Write once, run anywhere languages & Unrar for AIR

Tags: java, cross-platform, air, unrar, runtime-environment

I wanted to ask if there are any other Write Once, run anywhere languages like Java or AIR. I have mostly been a Java developer up till now, and a bit of Python and recently AIR has peaked my interest as I just found out about it.

Also I wanted to know if there are any unrar libraries for AIR or someway to read RAR archives with AIR, kind of like how you can with FZip and zip files. Kinda want a solution better than including binaries for Win/Lin/OSX with my program and using those based on the system.

Also I don't mind a compiled language as long as I can write 1 set of code, and it can be compiled to all the platforms with minimal to no changes. Kinda want to not use any OS Specific code or APIs, its why I asked for runtime languages like AIR or Java. Well Python is too, but it requires a bit of OS specific coding for file management.

Comment: Please post these as two separate questions.

Comment: Also, please make this community wiki.

Comment: OS-specific code for file management? Do you mean using `os.path`?

Comment: I mean like using system APIs to do file management. Instead of the languages API that handles the differences between systems through the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is also write once run everywhere.

Comment: Ah thanks for reminding me, but how easy is perl to distribute to people, where they would just run it? I guess there might be a packer kinda like java 2 exe or something where it just packs Perl in with the program, but that could be bulky.

Comment: It depends on the target OS.  IF Unix (AIX, Solaris, Linux, OS X) perl is available.  For windows, ActiveState and Cygwin both supply a free interpreter.

Comment: Yes, I want to write a small program, that I compile release whatever bytecode it is and people just run it to use it. AIR is like a 4 mb runtime, and installs quickly. Java almost everyone has. Perl isn't as popular on Windows, and very few people have an interpreter for it. This is gonna be a general use app.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Lua](http://www.lua.org). It is very similar to Python, lightweight and very portable.

YMMV depending on what you want to do with the language. If you're looking for a language with lots of bells and whistles you're probably better off with Python. That said, there are a lot of bindings for popular libraries available at [LuaForge](http://luaforge.net/)

Comment: Thx for reminding me about Lua. I used quite a bit of it making addons for Warhammer Online. Though for some of the stuff I want to do, I might have to use another language, but Lua allows a pretty easy way to run other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest this [Java API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-unrar/)  to un-rar file

Comment: Thanks, that can work if I bind to it from AIR or whatever I use. I was specifically looking for a AIR API or library or something, but it seems it might not be possible so I'll take what I can get.